# How to make vertical bars in flutter like shown in this picture

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

So I'm new to flutter and I want to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHYoD.jpg) . Also I will add onPressed function in this , when clicked the vertical bar will increase it's scale (as shown)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use container with height, width, color and borderRadius property inside a column.

Comment: Okay but how to increase its size when it is selected

Comment: for that I guess you can use RadioListTile because only one tile can be selected at once as per your UI.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered and upvote if it  helped. Thanks